# Should I use two commas for an adjective and nonrestrictive clause preceding a noun?

Tags: commas, clauses, non-restrictive, flow

I wrote the following sentence:

> A plain, usually blue, background with a seal in the center makes for a simplistic flag that breaks many design rules.

The commas surrounding "usually blue" seem correct, because it is a nonrestrictive clause. However, would "A plain, usually blue background with a seal in the center..." without the second comma be correct? It flows better and removes an awkward brake in the sentence. However, "usually blue" does act as a nonrestrictive clause because it describes "plain," and I have been taught that those should always be enclosed by commas.

Comment: What do you think of "a cold, stormy night"? If that is acceptable, then why not "a plain, usually blue background"?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan In "a cold, stormy night" "cold" and "stormy" describe "night" equally. However, "usually blue" is describing "plain" and acts as a nonrestrictive clause. Hence my doubt as to whether or not I can remove the comma.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to specify that "usually blue" should modify "plain" in the revised sentence. (That requirement isn't clear right now.)

Comment: *A plain background — usually blue — with a seal in the center...*